# Spring Tool Suite How To Exit Debug Perspective

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, sts

Hello I have stupidly allowed debug perspective for my gradle project.
However, now when ever I boot up my project it will load into debug perspective for some reason. The debug perspective is being much slower and I need to revert back. This is my current workspace.

[Image of workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdcOA.png)

As you can see I am in the JAVA perspective and the below picture is like this, I have set it to never change perspective.
[Preferences picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkxds.png)

What am I doing wrong I have changed multiple workspaces, but other projects aren't launching in this mode in the same workspace. But I can't seem to find anything in the project propeties which could be making this happen.

If you require any more screenshots/info please let me know :)
Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Go back to that preferences screen and press "Restore Defaults". Then, as long as you are _running_ and not _debugging_ the perspective should remain Java rather than debug.

Comment: I'm afraid even after doing that and right clicking on run as it still starts with debug.